# When applying for a position, how do I best reply to a question asking for skills I don’t have?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, recruitment

I am applying for a particular position where they have asked me if I have first-hand experience in protein crystallization and x-ray structure determination. I don’t have experience in any of those but I have mentioned my other experiences as asked. I lack only these.

How should I positively reply back so that it conforms my position there?

Comment: "No, but in preparation for this interview, I've studied those topics. And I think they're rather similar to [blah blah], which I do have experience in."

Comment: And if they ask you again, give them the theoritical bit and say, you are looking for more exposure in that area and would like to learn that area.

Answer (score 2):

No one ever has *all* the skills needed for a given position, unless it is well below your skill level, in which case you might be rejected as overqualified!

What prospective employers almost invariably want to hear is: motivation, motivation and motivation :) Acknowledge that you lack these skills, but assure them you are eager to learn them and study the theory behind the subject. Usually people learn best by doing.